# Angular: Accessing Attribute of a child component in parent

Tags: angularjs

I have my angular components like

```
<my-parent>
  <my-child ng-repeat="option in field.options">
    <!-- more html -->
 </my-child>
</my-parent>
```

In My parent component's ngAfterViewInit, I am trying to access the child component like

```
const repeatElement = this.$element.find('my-child[ng-repeat]');
```

but not able to do so. 
Note: $element service is injected to component's class constructor..

When I debugged this I found by the time ngAfterViewInit is getting executed, DOM does not have my-child component..

Earlier.. this logic was there in directive's compile function which was working fine.. but Now I am converting this to Angular and got stuck here. Any help would be highly appreciated..